# Are there vulnerabilities in display connections?

Tags: malware, hardware

I have been in the market for a DisplayPort KVM. Most of these products come from small companies I have never heard of and possibly do not trust. I understand the risk of plugging in USB to any machine and what it can execute to compromise a machine.

If I ignore the USB ports and only use the DisplayPort connections (this could also go for HDMI, DVI, VGA, etc), what is the possibilities that your computer could be secretly compromised with some form of malware through these ports?

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I did search for this item, but did not find this.

Answer (score -1):

HDMI, DVI, VGA ports aren't networked. There are no packets to pass through them. They can however be spliced/split to enable recording but this would need to be done on premise (local). You could go the [KVM over IP](http://www.raritan.com/products/kvm-switches) which can be configured as secured as you want them to be. (Shove them in a VPN tunnel, allocate firewall rules, over SSL, etc)

Comment: This is incorrect. VGA/HDMI connections involve the display sending the EDID (possibly with extended data) to the computer. The EDID parser can be compromised and, at least in one case I know for an embedded device, lead just to that. CEC and HEC (for HDMI) has an even bigger attack surface area which has also lead to exploitation.